# Method overriding and inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

```
public class Circle {

    public static final double PI = 3.141592654;
    protected double radius;

    public Circle(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Class = " + getClass().getSimpleName() + " (radius = " + radius + ")";
    }
}


public class PlaneCircle extends Circle {

    private double centerX, centerY;

    public PlaneCircle(double radius, double centerX, double centerY) {
        super(radius);
        this.centerX = centerX;
        this.centerY = centerY;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

Suppose the above two classes are in different files.

When I create an instance of `PlaneCircle` (in another java file) like the following two lines...

```
PlaneCircle planeCircle1 = new PlaneCircle(3, 6, 7);
System.out.println(planeCircle1.toString());
```

What I get in the Console output is

```
Class = PlaneCircle (radius = 3.0)
```

The `toString()` method in `PlaneCircle` calls `super.toString()`, and the `toString()` method in `Circle` should give "Circle" when I use the `getClass().getSimpleName()`.

My question is, why the output is "PlaneCircle" instead of "Circle" in this case even though I have created an instance of the subclass (PlaneCircle)? Does this have anything to do with reflection?

Comment: The object on which the method is getting invoked matters. In this case, the object is PlainCircle and you will get PlanCircle in toString

Comment: The constant PI is already defined in `Math` class. See [`Math.PI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#PI).

Answer (score 4):

`planeCircle1` is an instance of `PlaneCircle`, which means `getClass()` would return `PlaneCircle.class` (i.e. the `Class` instance that represents the `PlaneCircle` class) and `getClass().getSimpleName()` would return that class's name - "PlaneCircle".

It doesn't matter that `getClass().getSimpleName()` is called from a method of the base class `Circle`, since when you call a method without an instance variable, you are calling it on the current instance (i.e. `getClass()` is the same as `this.getClass()`, and `this` is an instance of `PlaneCircle` in your code sample).

Answer (score 1):

`getClass()` is also polymorphic - it returns a `Class` object that represents the instance it belongs to, in this case, a `PlaneCircle`. If you don't want this behavior, you could either hard code `Circle`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Class = circle (radius = " + radius + ")";
}
```

Or statically access the `Circle` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Class = " + Circle.class.getSimpleName() + " (radius = " + radius + ")";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are operating on an instance of `PlaneCircle` and not `Circle`, `getClass.getSimpleName()` will be called on your current instance of `PlaneCircle`. 
With the current setup you may not be able to print "Circle" using polymorphic behavior. At Runtime, methods of PlaneCircle will be called.

Comment: Did you test the code? My side still shows the same result with your code.